# DC and Nyquist values are higher than all other bins

Tags: fft

I am using a mean centered signal and applying fft to it, however the dc and nyquist values are a lot higher than all other values. Wondering if I am doing anything wrong or need to add anything else. The first image is the signal and the other is the fft output.

[image: This is the signal]

[image: This is the fft output]

```
load Dog_1_interictal_segment_0001.mat

%interictal_segement is a struct with a 16 x 10000 matrix named data
data=interictal_segment_1.data;

%take first two seconds of the first eeg channel
data=data(1,1:10000);
freq=5000;
N=freq*2;
hz=linspace(0,freq/2,N);

averaged_mean=data-mean(data);
channel_frequency=abs(fft(averaged_mean)/N).^2;

figure(1)
plot(averaged_mean)

figure(2)
plot(hz,channel_frequency,'ko-','markerfacecolor','m','linew',1)
xlabel('Frequency (norm.)'), ylabel('Power');
```

Comment: The bins at the right-hand side of the graph are actually negative "low-ish" frequencies. 

Fs/2 is actually in the middle of your graph.

Comment: What is a mean centered signal?

Comment: @Ben can you please elaborate I am relatively new to signal processing and would appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: @DSPRookie I did signal=signal-mean(signal) to remove any initial offset

Comment: You could use the fftshift function so that the frequency axis would go from -fs/2 to fs/2

Comment: your x-axis isn't properly labeled: nothing about the frequency axis here looks normalized (norm.)!

Comment: In your you have a variable first_channel, what is that? I cannot find the assignment statement for first_channel.

Comment: @DSPRookie sorry that should be averaged_mean, I fixed it up

Answer (score 2):

For a mean centered (DC removed, pure AC) signal the first bin of the FFT output should be an exact zero. In your plot, this zero output sample is possibly obscured by the squeezing of the graph display; i.e., if you zoom into the left side of your plot, you should see that zero valued first bin sample...

Furthermore, for a typical FFT computation of real data, the second half of the FFT bins, is a conjugate symmetric mirror of the first half (excluding the DC and / or the Nyquist bins). Note that the Nyquist bin is (about) at the center of the FFT output, and to the right of this Nyquist bin is the mirrored content. Note also that exact Nyquist frequency bin exists only for even length FFTs and not for odd length FFTs.

Looking into your output, the last and the first bins seem like mirrors; but that's wrong as I have indicated, your fist FFT bin must be a zero, and even if it's not zero, it won't be mirrored to the last bin. What's mirrored to the last bin is actually the second bin of the FFT output.

Comment: so the issue is that I did not correctly set the number of bins? I currently have hz=linspace(0,freq/2,N) where N is the number of time points. However, N should be half of the number of time points?

Comment: it's better if you post your code.

Comment: I pasted my code feel free to look at it

Comment: @Hvjay I've checked your code. First, you are not displaying FFT magnitude, but normalized FFT magnitude square. It's something similar to PSD periodogram estimate. Second, as I've predicted, your DC bin is indeed **zero**, but it's obscured in the plot window.You must zoom into your DC bin and see that it's zero indeed. So your plot is correct. There's no problem in your plot.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly what you are referring to as Nyquist is actually low frequency components, what you plotted is a non shifted FFT, using fftshift function in Matlab, you will find that the right side of your figure will appear as negative low frequency components starting from DC. Basically the true spectrum is just everything from 1250 to 2500 shifted left by 2500.

Also since you would have used randn from MATLAB to simulate noise, it is no guarantee than the noise itslef will be zero mean. The "expected value" of noise is zero mean, not particular realizations. So even though you have subtracted DC from the signal, the Noise would still be non zero mean hence the DC bin with non zero value. Otherwise please paste the code, to inspect further.

Comment: I pasted the code for you to take a look